# The bitwise operation error for jpg and png images

Tags: python-3.x, bitwise-operators, opencv3.0

I get stuck in a wired problem. A very simple example of bitwise operation. However, it will show error when treating png images.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import cv2
image = mpimg.imread('test1.png')
mask = np.zeros((image.shape[0], image.shape[1], 3), dtype=np.uint8)
result = cv2.bitwise_and(image,mask)
```

It will show the following error about bitwise_and:

**The operation is neither 'array op array' (where arrays have the same size and type), nor 'array op scalar', nor 'scalar op array' in function binary_op**

The operation does not have error when treating test2.jpg

test1.png
[image: test1.png]

test2.jpg
[image: test2.jpg]

**I know the first image looks like a gray image but it does have three channels!**

Answer (score 0):

I think .png images have four channels (one for opacity). So you try to operate on two images which has different numbers of channels (jpg - 3 and png - 4).

Comment: I checked the png image. The mpimg.imread only read the first three channels

Comment: You should try `mask = np.zeros((image.shape[0], image.shape[1], image.shape[2]), dtype=np.uint8)` just to be sure they are of the same size.